# failing to display bootstrap UI Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-idle

In my AngularJS application I am using the `ngIdle` module and following the demo that the author has shared on his Github https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/.

I have all the right dependencies injected, and all the right CDNs loaded, and the functions are running, but it seems my controllers can't access `bootstrap-ui` `$uibModal`.

My CDNs and files are loaded as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-idle/1.3.2/angular-idle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Required modules for both `ui-bootstrap` and `ngIdel` are injected as so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngIdle', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

And my controller, which is within an Angular `component`, also has the required injections as such:

```
app.component('patents', {
    bindings: { patents: '<' },
    templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/patents/views/list-patents.htm',
    controller: function($state, $scope, Idle, Keepalive, $uibModal) {

    $scope.started = false;

        function closeModals() {
        if ($scope.warning) {
          $scope.warning.close();
          $scope.warning = null;
        }

        if ($scope.timedout) {
          $scope.timedout.close();
          $scope.timedout = null;
        }
        }

      $scope.$on('IdleStart', function() {
        closeModals();
        $scope.warning = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'warning-dialog.html',
          windowClass: 'modal-danger'
        });
      });

      $scope.$on('IdleEnd', function() {
        closeModals();
      });
});
```

***Question***

Why when the functions are running and no errors are being returned, is the modal not opening when the user is Idel? HTML below provided below.

```
<section>
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-hide="started" ng-click="start()">Start Demo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="started" ng-click="stop()">Stop Demo</button>
  </p>
</section>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="warning-dialog.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>You're Idle. Do Something!</h3>
  </div>
  <div idle-countdown="countdown" ng-init="countdown=5" class="modal-body">
   <uib-progressbar max="5" value="5" animate="false" class="progress-striped active">You'll be logged out in {{countdown}} second(s).</uib-progressbar>
  </div>

</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="timedout-dialog.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h3>You've Timed Out!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <p>
      You were idle too long. Normally you'd be logged out, but in this demo just do anything and you'll be reset.
   </p>
 </div>
</script>
```

Comment: what browser console says ?

Comment: It doesn't. No errors returned. Even when the functions are invoked, I can log a message just fine, but the `$uibModal` won't run

Comment: Not sure though; but may be CSS issue ? have you checked by inspecting DOM in chrome whether it generates Modal or not ?

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap 4 css; can you try using bootstrap 3 css ? Not sure though !

Comment: @RahulNaik you are right about the Bootstrap 3. I need to update the classes used. Write your comment as an answer and I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything fine here except bootstrap css.
I believe you need to include bootstrap 3 CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

because you are using angular ui bootstrap uibModal and its template does include bootstrap 3 classes and including bootstrap 3 css modal popup should work.

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: np bro...happy coding